# python3.7 optionparser input option with asterisk(*) becomes a file in the folder

Tags: python, optionparser

#### Env:

> python3.7
>   OptionParser with a option [ add_option('-t', '--target', action='append', dest='targets') ]
>   OS: CentOS7.6

#### Problem:

> So I am using this option to input a list of targets, and with this command line:
>   `parser -t logs* -t test`
>   there's a file "logs.tar.gz" in where I execute this command line, 
>   when i print the value of targets, this is what i get:
>   `['logs.tar.gz', 'test']`
>   So I believe this is a 'problem' of system level, and what I want to know is:
>   is there any way to make `logs*` be `logs*` without input `logs\*` in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is who is expanding the `*`. There is nothing that python can do here since it never gets to know about the `log*`.

You can force your shell to interpret the `*` as a literal value with some quoting:

```
parser -t "logs*" -t test
```

This works in zsh, it might be different for your shell.

Comment: you are right, looks like for centos i have to use literal string as the option! Thank you!